# Passing the value from a .txt file to a cmd prompt variable

Tags: cmd, sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S abcd\SQLEXPRESS -i C:\Users\myName\Desktop\SQLQuery1.sql -h -1 -o C:\Users\myName\Desktop\resultOfQuery.txt
set /p varname= < C:\Users\myName\Desktop\resultOfQuery.txt
echo %varname%
```

I am getting an error, Unexpected Argument .

The command set /p varname is not working correctly.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but should it not be `-h 1`?

Comment: It should , as I want to remove the heading.Anyways , I got the answer , I am missing -E for trusted security and -d for database name . Thanks :)